# Deactivate "Recent Files" in Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

I want to deactivate the "recent files" in the sidebar of dolphin.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI is in `System Settings - Workspace Behaviour - Activities - Privacy` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Then how do we get it to work? That option would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least hide them by right clicking on the sidebar and unchecking the option "Show all entries".

If you just want to clean up the application's look, this might work for you. You can also click on "unlock panels" to move, show/hide and delete the sidebar, menu bar or terminal as you see fit. Of course, this is no option if you want to protect your privacy.

Answer (score 0):

right click on recent files and select to hide the section